# Error while running pipeline shell script in jenkins

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, github

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    tools{
        maven "maven"
    }

    stages{

        stage('git scm'){

            steps{
                git changelog: false, poll: false, url:'https://github.com/saikishore789/SampleMaven.git'
            }
        }
    
            stage('build'){
                steps{
                    
                sh "mvn package"
            }
            }
    }
}
```

After running this script build got failed and displaying this error:

```
Cannot run program "nohup" (in directory "C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\Pipeline-project1"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: I am going to with `nohup` is a unix command and `C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local` is a Windows machine, so won't be found. Search S/O for ["[jenkins] nohup 'c:\' is:question"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjenkins%5D+nohup+%27c%3A%5C%27+is%3Aquestion) for suggestions to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a windows node, try to use this step `bat`step instead of `sh`:

```
stage('build'){
                steps{
                    
                bat "mvn package"
                 }
             }
```